# What is the relationship between surreal star and the empty set?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

In [Surreal Numbers and Games](http://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/2010/surreal.pdf) on page 6 it says that $0=\{\emptyset|\emptyset\}$.

Additionally, on page 10 it says that $*+*=0$ and that for any value $x$ we have $x+*=\{x|x\}$.

Given the previous, it seems logical that both $*+*=\{*|*\}=0$ and $\emptyset+*=\{\emptyset|\emptyset\}=0$ are true.

This looks to me like $*$ and $\emptyset$ could be equivalent because given $x+*=0$, $*$ and $\emptyset$ both seem like valid solutions for $x$.

However I have not read anywhere that $*$ and $\emptyset$ are equivalent, so I am not sure if they are or if they are not.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, that PDF skips over some key clarifications about notation that may have led to some confusion. I would not recommend learning from it without external support like lectures or another more detailed text.

> for any value $x$ we have $x+∗=\{x\mid x\}$.

The context in the PDF is that this holds when $x$ is a number. If $x$ is some other game (like $\{0\mid*\}$), this equation can fail.

> Given the previous, it seems logical that both $∗+∗=\{∗\mid∗\}=0$ and
>   $\emptyset+∗=\{\emptyset\mid\emptyset\}=0$ are true.

$∗+∗=\{∗\mid∗\}=0$ is true. But we need to take more care when evaluating something like $\emptyset+∗$. Since every game is an ordered pair of games, $\emptyset$ is not a game. However, there is a convention, used-but-not-explained in the addition section of that PDF for expressions that look like adding a set to a game. If $S$ is a set of games and $g$ is a game, $S+g$ is a shorthand for "the set of all games of the form $s+g$, for some $s$ in $S$". So $\emptyset+∗$ is a set, not a game like $0$. In particular, it's the set $\emptyset$.

> This looks to me like $∗$ and $\emptyset$ could be equivalent because given $x+∗=0$,
>   $∗$ and $\emptyset$ both seem like valid solutions for $x$.

As discussed above, $\emptyset+*$ is not $0$ -- it's not even a game. But you are right that "$g+*=0$ and $h+*=0$" would imply "$g=h$". In fact, you could add $*$ to both sides of $g+*=0$ to find $g+*+*=*$ so that $g+0=*$ and $g=*$. This idea works in general; negatives of games are unique (up to equality).

> However I have not read anywhere that ∗ and ∅ are equivalent, so I am
>   not sure if they are or if they are not.

Just to emphasize one more time: $*$ is a game and $\emptyset$ is a set. They're different sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks for another excellent answer! Is there a 'double set' notation for $\emptyset$ (eg. $\emptyset=\{x|x\}$ or $\emptyset=\{x|y\}$)? My guess is that there is not. However I am not sure.

Comment: @user773237 Maybe MJD's new answer has already cleared this up for you, but this double set notation is a way to notate games, and it's just a shorthand for an ordered pair of sets of games, which MJD writes $\langle S,T\rangle$ and I would more-often write $(S,T)$. $\emptyset$ denotes the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) $\{\}$. A set with nothing in it certainly isn't a game, or an ordered pair of any kind, so there cannot be any "double set" notation for it. Your question is somewhat analogous to "Is there a decimal notation for "fish"? (e.g. fish=1.3)"

Answer (score 2):

$0$ and $\ast$ are games.  $\emptyset$ is not a game, it's a *set* of games.

A “game” is a pair of *sets* of games.  Usually we write a pair of sets as $\langle\{\ell_1, \ell_2\}, \{r_1, r_2\}\rangle$ but in combinatorial game theory we abbreviate this to $\{\ell_1, \ell_2\mid r_1, r_2\}$.

When one or both of the sets is empty we  just leave that half of the notation empty.  So for example, $1$ is a game whose left set is $\{0\}$ and whose right set is $\emptyset$.  The usual notation would be $\langle \{0\}, \emptyset\rangle$ but in abbreviated form it is $\{ 0\mid \,\}$.

Representation of games in this way is not unique.  Two different pairs of sets might represent equivalent games.  You're right that $\ast+\ast = \{\ast\mid\ast\}$.  But the $\ast$s on the left and right turn out not to affect the value, and $\{\ast\mid\ast\} = \{\,\mid\,\} = 0$.  You can see why this should be if you consider  some game $G$ where one player has a winning strategy.  Do they also have a winning strategy in $G + \{\ast\mid\ast\}$?  Definitely.  (You work out the details.)  In the jargon, we say that the extra $\ast$ options in $\{\ast\mid\ast\}$ can be ignored because they are “reversible”.

The expression $\emptyset+\ast$ is what is called an “abuse of notation”. It is using the $+$ symbol in a way that is similar to, but not the same as, its normal meaning.  Normally, $+$ operates on two games and yields a new game, the sum.  But in expressions like $$x+y = \{X_L + y, x+Y_L\mid
X_R+y, x+Y_R\}$$ we use the $+$ in a slightly different way.  The $x+Y_L$ is a shorthand for the *set* consisting of everything that you can get by adding $x$ to *some* member of the set $Y_L$.  If $Y_L$ is $\emptyset$, then $x+Y_L$ is also empty, because there is nothing of that form.
The comma actually denotes the *union* of the two sets $X_L+y$ and $x+Y_L$.

We would normally write “$x+Y_L$” as “$\{x + \ell \mid \ell \in Y_L\}$”, so you can see why we need the abbreviation!

The book does *not* say that “for any value $x$ we have $x+\ast = \{x\mid x\}$”.  It says that is true for any *number* $x$.  In general, for games that are not numbers, it is not true.  One counterexample is a game called $\ast2 $ for which $\ast2 + \ast \ne0$ but $\{\ast2 \mid \ast2\} = 0$.

Comment: I agree with every claim here except "The expression $\emptyset+*$ does not make sense", since it has to make some sort of sense for us to implement the definition of game addition given in the notes linked in the OP.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it seems to me OP didn't understand that  $+$ was being used in  two different ways. Often this sort of abuse of notation causes no confusion, but this time it did. I'll revise the answer.